# Why am I unable to connect to certain WiFi networks?

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-6

We have a UniFi WiFi access point at our office, which has both a 2.4 GHz and a 5 GHz network.

I am unable to connect to either network, even though I have no problem connecting to any other WiFi network and other devices can also connect just fine to the UniFi networks.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to connect to the UniFi networks you need to change your **Wi-Fi frequency band** from **Automatic** to *either* 5 GHz or 2.4 GHz.

As long as the mode is set to automatic, you will not be able to connect to either network. *Why* that is, is unclear to me. However [other users](http://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless/nexus-5x-refuses-to-connect-to-uap-s/td-p/1493233) reported similar problems.

Comment: That's a) Super weird, and also b) Qualifies as a driver/wireless stack bug. Note also c) Many android manufacturers have hidden the 2.4/5Ghz menu